# What is the purpose of __next id in nextjs?

Tags: css, next.js

What is the purpose of "__next" id in nextjs. Can I use it for css? I need to carry height: 100%; inside the div of "__next" id from body.

I need to apply css to div with "__next" id. I want to know wheather it is good practice among the developers.

Comment: Double underscore is used to denote `global variables` in typescript -- It's a convention, not a requirement.  But it's there so the variable `next` is not confused with the global `__next` should you try to declare the former.